# Removing data from a column and using this substring data for WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column storing an ID joined with an account number by a "-"

Example: 1000-701000000788917

I need to be able to write a WHERE clause where if the first nunber is 2000 to ignore the record all together, but if the result does not start with 2000 to strip the first 5 characters and record just 701000000788917 in the column of the destination table.

Comment: You can use CASE in the WHERE clause. Just beware of performance implications--especially if you're using functions too.

Comment: You want to select only those records where ID is other than 2000?

Comment: Yes, I want to ignore all records that start with "2000-" but in my destination table I want to also drop the first 5 characters so would record in the table as "701000000788917" instead of "1000-701000000788917"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these approaches

```
declare @u varchar(max)= '2000-701000000788917'
declare @y varchar(max)= '1000-701000000788917'

select substring(@y,CharIndex('-',@y) + 1,len(@y)) --- get everything after the hyphen

select * from Table where  substring(@u,0,4)  != '2000'  -- get where the first 4 char are not equal to 2000
```

Comment: Thank you! CharIndex was the way to go!

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
INSERT NewTable (NewID)
SELECT SUBSTRING(ID,6,LEN(ID)) AS ID
FROM MyTable
WHERE LEFT(ID,5) <> '2000-';
```

This assumes your starting ID is 4 characters.

Comment: This works on my test, will try further and will give you credit if so. Thank you

Comment: @Rob Also check out the other answers which have a more dynamic `SELECT` (using `CHARINDEX`).  If your ID's are guarnateed only 4 characters then this is good.  If they're variable length you should include the `CHARINDEX` check.

Comment: Thanks! CHARINDEX was the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  RIGHT(ID, Len(ID) - CharIndex('-', ID))
FROM    YourTable
WHERE   ID NOT LIKE '2000-%'
```

It will exclude every thing before first '-' character.